# How do i upload, insert to database and rename files in php?

Tags: php

I have some problem in my project, i'm making a manga reader website, and i make a chapter pictures in multiple form, so here is the code

```
$manga_id = $_GET['manga_id'];          
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("task3");
    $chapternumber = $_POST['chapternumber'];
    $chaptertitle = $_POST['chaptertitle'];

        $a=0;
        foreach ($_FILES['pictures']['name'] as $filename) 
        {
            $tmp=$_FILES['pictures']['tmp_name'][$a];
            $target = "C:\\wamp\\www\\task\\comic\\images\\chapter\\".$_FILES['pictures']['name'][$a];
            move_uploaded_file($tmp, $target);
            rename("images/chapter/$filename","images/chapter/$manga_id-$chapternumber-$a.jpg");
            $a=$a + 1;
            mysql_query("insert into chapter(ID_Komik,No_Chapter,ch_title,Halaman,pictures) 
            values ('$manga_id','$chapternumber','$chaptertitle','$a','$manga_id-$chapternumber-$a.jpg')"); 
        }

        header("Location: main.php?page=manga&&manga_id=$manga_id");
```

what's wrong with my syntax? the files in database has been renamed but the files doesn't move to the target, i'm a newbie in php but i must try harder, please answer it, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: the target folders already exist? or do you create them dynamicly? do you have writing permissions for the target folders? for better debugging use var_dump on your vars/functions to get some result to analyse

Answer (score 0):

In

> $target

you should use relative path to your php file

for example:

> $target = "images\chapter\".$_FILES['pictures']['name'][$a];

good luck!